# Scroll into view element hides behind header

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, scrollview

I am making a react application where on click over an item below select box the respective item in next section gets scrolled.

**Working Example for above said scenario:** https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-into-view-in-react-7xtq9

Eg: Click on Item two, then its respective field set will gets scrolled to top..

**Issue:**

-> Now the requirement is that I need to add a header and below the header, both the sections needs to be displayed.

-> I have added `style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}` to the container div like,

```
   <div id="container" style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
    <div className="_2iA8p44d0WZ">
      <span className="chip _7ahQImy">Item One</span>
      <span className="chip _7ahQImy">Item Two</span>
      <span className="chip _7ahQImy">Item Three</span>
      <span className="chip _7ahQImy">Item Four</span>
      <span className="chip _7ahQImy">Item Five</span>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="searchBox"
        id="search_input"
        placeholder="Select"
        autoComplete="off"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
  </div>
```

-> This makes the container to display below header.

**1)** -> But when I click on any item, then this `container` div gets hidden behind fixed header.

**2)** -> Also the scrolled element as well gets hidden behind header.

**Expected Result:**

-> The container section and the scrolled element needs to be visible from top even if any of the item was clicked.

-> To be simple it **should not** hide behind header and needs to be displayed below header.

**Current working example:**

[image: Edit scroll-into-view-in-react (forked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to apply the styles to the outer container that is wrapping the container you want scrollable. This is the `div` rendering both the fixed position header and the content.

To the outer `div`

1. Add the `margin-top: 100px` to push content down.
2. Set a height that restricts the content from just expanding the height automatically, `height: calc(100vh - 100px)`, the height of the view window minus the height of the header. ***Note:** In the codesandbox I tweaked to `99vh` to keep the window's scrollbar from appearing, so you'll likely need to tweak these values for your real code.*
3. Hide the overflowing content and automatically display scrollbars when overflow occurs, `overflow: auto`.
4. Remove the in-line `style` prop from the inner content `div`.

Code

```
<div
  style={{
    marginTop: "100px",
    height: "calc(99vh - 100px)",
    overflow: "auto"
  }}
>
  {/* Nav */}
  <div id="container">
    <div className="_2iA8p44d0WZ">
      // content
    </div>
  </div>
  {/* fieldsets */}
</div>
```

[image]

[image: Edit scroll-into-view-element-hides-behind-header]

Comment: Bro, Please kindly help me here bro https://stackoverflow.com/q/66141345/13270726

Comment: @fish-404 Thanks for the interest, but HTML and element attributes work a little differently when using JSX and React.