# Get selected item and its count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cart, shopping-cart

I am trying to make a shopping cart app like [this site](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) but using **reactjs**.

**index.js**: (Sending each product to product `component`)

```
        {products.length > 0
          ? products.map((product) => (
              <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
            ))
          : ""}
```

**components/product.js**:

```
<div>
    {product?.price}
   <h3>
      {product.name ? product.name : ""}
   </h3>
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product?.description }} />
</div>
```

Also I have the ADD button UI switch code and that will look like,

Before clicking add button,

```
------------
| ADD     +|
------------
```

After clicking add button,

```
-----------------
| -  {count}   +|
-----------------
```

Things are fine as of now and the respective count(s) on each product individually gets added in home page.

Also with the help of [contextApi](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) made an `AppContext` and updated the cart like,

```
  const addToCart = (product) => {
    if (+cart >= 0) {
      setCart(+cart + 1);
      setCartItems(product);
    }
  };
```

In **nav.js**, I am getting the updated count of the products but when I click on the bag menu (Which is a **cart page**) , I am unable to fetch the context.

**Expected Result**

While visiting the cart page (On click of the bag menu in header), the page would display the so far selected product (with name and description) along with their quantity respectively.

**Current Result:**

Unable to get the appcontext data and display the selected product along with the quantity.

**Working Snippet:**

[image: Edit Using Tailwind with Next.js (forked)]

Please kindly help me to achieve the result of displaying the selected product and its respective quantity while navigating to cart (bag) page.. I am struggling with this for long.. So I humbly request you to help me with right solution.. Big thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. You've multiple `AppProvider` components each providing a different context to their wrapped children.
2. The initial `AppContext` shape doesn't match what is *actually* passed as the context's value.
3. The `cartItems` state isn't maintained as an array.
4. Other various issues and patterns

## Solution

1. Remove all the extraneous `AppProvider` provider components, use just one to wrap your entire app in `_app.js`.

   ```
   import { AppProvider } from "../components/context/AppContext";

   export default class TailwindApp extends App {
     render() {
       const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
       return (
         <AppProvider>
           <Component {...pageProps} />
         </AppProvider>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Fix the context to have an initial value that matches the provided value. Fix the state updaters to correctly manage the `cartItems` array. Use an `useEffect` hook to compute the derived total item count state when the `cartItems` array state updates. Correctly add and update item/product quantities, and remove item when quantity reaches 0.

   ```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

   export const AppContext = React.createContext({
     cart: 0,
     cartItems: [],
     setCart: () => {},
     addToCart: () => {},
     removeFromCart: () => {}
   });

   export const AppProvider = (props) => {
     const [cart, setCart] = useState(0);

     const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
       setCart(cartItems.reduce((count, { quantity }) => count + quantity, 0));
     }, [cartItems]);

     const addToCart = (product) => {
       setCartItems((items) => {
         if (items.find(({ id }) => id === product.id)) {
           return items.map((item) =>
             item.id === product.id
               ? {
                   ...item,
                   quantity: item.quantity + 1
                 }
               : item
           );
         } else {
           return [
             ...items,
             {
               ...product,
               quantity: 1
             }
           ];
         }
       });
     };

     const removeFromCart = (product) => {
       setCartItems((items) => {
         const foundItem = items.find(({ id }) => id === product.id);
         if (foundItem?.quantity > 1) {
           return items.map((item) =>
             item.id === product.id
               ? {
                   ...item,
                   quantity: item.quantity - 1
                 }
               : item
           );
         } else {
           return items.filter(({ id }) => id !== product.id);
         }
       });
     };

     return (
       <AppContext.Provider value={{ cart, addToCart, removeFromCart, cartItems }}>
         {props.children}
       </AppContext.Provider>
     );
   };
   ```
3. In `Products.js` remove all the local item count state, quantities can be accessed from state in the context. Conditionally render the "Add Item" and increment/decrement buttons on the item count.

   ```
   import Link from "next/link";
   import { useContext } from "react";
   import { AppContext } from "./context/AppContext";

   const Product = (props) => {
     const { product } = props;
     const contextData = useContext(AppContext);

     const count =
       contextData.cartItems.find(({ id }) => id === product.id)?.quantity ?? 0;

     const addToCart = (product) => () => {
       contextData.addToCart(product);
     };
     const removeFromCart = (product) => () => {
       contextData.removeFromCart(product);
     };

     return (
       ...

           {count ? (
             ...
                 {count}
             ...
           ) : (
             ...
                 <span className="label">ADD</span>
             ...
           )}
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
4. In `Cart.js` you can import and consume the context to render and display the cart items.

   ```
   import { useContext } from "react";
   import { AppContext } from "../components/context/AppContext";

   const Cart = () => {
     const { cart, cartItems } = useContext(AppContext);

     return (
       <div>
         <h1> Cart Page </h1>
         <h2>Total Item Count: {cart}</h2>
         <p>
           <ul>
             {cartItems.map(({ id, name, quantity }) => (
               <li key={id}>
                 {name}: {quantity}
               </li>
             ))}
           </ul>
         </p>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

***Note:** Please note that an `id` property was added to all items/products in your `products` array to make matching/identifying them a much easier task.*

## Demo

[image: Edit Using Tailwind with Next.js (forked)]

Comment: I am really much thankful for your solution at right time bro.. Sorry for disturbing with additional requests.. **1)** I would like to get to know how can I modify the quantity of the product in cart page and update the context in common? **2)** How can I make a total price calculation? **(Should I need to do it in cart page or in context?)**

Comment: Accepted your answer bro.. Also if you could help me to solve the above two requests, then that would be very much helpful for me.. A big thanks once again bro..

Comment: @Undefined To (1) modify the quantities on the cart page you can simply destructure `addToCart` and `removeFromCart` and render buttons in the mapped items and pass the product the same way it was done in the `Product` component. (2) to compute a total price can be derived from the `cartItems` array, just reduce the cart array to a total where each cart item's cost is `quantitiy * price`. I see that your prices are strings that include the currency. You may want to convert your data to store a numerical `price` value and you can later append whatever currency symbol you need later.

Comment: Thanks for your comment bro.. I feel that I am completely disturbing you.. But could you update the codesandbox with new solution bro? .. I am very sorry for this..

Comment: @Undefined forked a new one: https://codesandbox.io/s/using-tailwind-with-nextjs-forked-w0bk4?file=/pages/cart.js

Comment: You are awesome bro.. This solves all my issues.. Once again big thanks for quick and best solution bro..

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `AppProvider` to `_app.js` and remove it from both `index.js` and `cart.js` then both pages will be able to access the same context.

Your `_app.js` should look like this

```
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import { AppProvider } from "../components/context/AppContext";

export default class TailwindApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <AppProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AppProvider>
    );
  }
}
```